# Google Spreadsheet a column mirrors a different columns values when it shouldnt be

Tags: google-sheets

Ive been working on a spreadsheet to examine something. I was converting a recursive formula into a linear one. The initial value or first state was 60. To get to the second state you 240. This is done by taking the previous state, doubling it, and adding 120. Which leads to the 3rd and 4th states of 600 and 1320. Now this base formula was clear enough that the `(60+120)*2^(n-1)-120` accurately expresses it.

My second part comes from needing to add in the ability to decrease the costs while still staying true to the state. So the last formula only works when the cost reduction is 0. After considerable effort (I kept having minor rounding errors) I arrived at `(ROUND(60-60*0.015*B$2)+(120-round(120*rounddown(B$2/3)*0.03,0)))*2^($A2-1)-(120-round(120*rounddown(B$2/3)*0.03,0))`.

To test the formulas I created a table with the following values, with a2=1 to a5=4, and b2=0 to h2=6. Now I was using google spreadsheets to examine the information. When I populate the table I found that all the values were correct with the formula, except on G. On G the values are identical to F.
So to try and correct this I have deleted the information from the cells, deleted the columns, and even tried again in a new spreadsheet. But in all cases G=F when it should not. I cant figure out why I'm getting a duplicate column.

The information on row 3 is the values that it should be using.

The expected values are G4=55, G5=226, G6=568, G7=1252.

[image: Screen shot of google spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know, I finally managed to solve the issue. I needed to round in one more place. The following is the formula that has worked for my current testing.

sum((ROUND(60-round(60*0.015*A$2))+(120-round(120*rounddown(A$2/3)*0.03,0)))*2^($A25-1)-(120-round(120*rounddown(A$2/3)*0.03,0)))